# Application force close while loading from sqllite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

From my sqllite database in asset folder, i load latitude and longitude of markers for my google map.  On run, the activity force closed with the error log below.

```
09-11 13:57:33.187: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.296: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLitepackageException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.312: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.328: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.328: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.328: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.343: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.343: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.359: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
09-11 13:57:33.359: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
09-11 13:57:33.359: W/System.err(6560):     at package.db.DBHelper.getArticlesList(DBHelper.java:234)
09-11 13:57:33.359: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:656)
09-11 13:57:33.375: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.375: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.db.DBHelper.getArticlesList(DBHelper.java:234)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:656)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.db.DBHelper.getArticlesList(DBHelper.java:234)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:656)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.db.DBHelper.getArticlesList(DBHelper.java:234)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:656)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 13:57:33.382: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 13:57:33.390: W/System.err(6560):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at package.db.DBHelper.getArticlesList(DBHelper.java:234)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:656)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at package.maps.Map$loadingTask.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/System.err(6560):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 13:57:33.414: W/dalvikvm(6560): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence"
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
09-11 13:57:33.421: W/System.err(6560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
09-11 13:57:33.445: W/dalvikvm(6560): threadid=26: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
```

*

In my database, the table gps exist but in the log above (no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence") it does not find the table gps.  At first i believe cursor was not closed.  How can this be possible. i am using android 2.3 to test my application.

Here is my code:

```
public class DBHelper {

    private final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/s../databases/";
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "bfcoi.sqlite";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static String mtype="Agence";

    public static String db_help="ON";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    OpenHelper openHelper=null;
    StringBuilder query =null;
    Cursor cursor=null;

    ArticlesTable articlesTable=new ArticlesTable();
    DestinateurTable destinataireTable = new DestinateurTable();
    MailSentTable mailsentTable= new MailSentTable();

    public static DBHelper dbHelper = null;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        try {

            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(dbHelper == null)
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        return dbHelper;
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE) ;
        //SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);////

    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        if(getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context) == false){
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(context);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    private class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

        public OpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }


    public void setDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnceFlag(Context ctx){

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        boolean isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce = prefs.getBoolean("isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce", false);
        return isDBAlreadyCopiedToDeviceOnce; 

    }

    ////////////////////////////
    //// Write your methods here
    ////////////////////////////

    public ArrayList<Article> getArticlesList() {

        ArrayList<Article> items=new ArrayList<Article>();

        try {

            query = new StringBuilder();

            /*
             * SEARCH BY TYPE i.e. Distributeur/Agence
             */

            if (db_help.equals("ON"))
                query.append("select * FROM "+articlesTable.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE type=\""+mtype+"\"");

            /*
             * SEARCH / DISPLAY IN LISTVIEW
             */

            else if (db_help.equals("EXEPTION")){
                query.append("SELECT * FROM gps WHERE adresse6 LIKE '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%' OR adressE1 LIKE  '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse2 LIKE '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse3 LIKE '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse4 LIKE '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse5 LIKE '%"+MapsSearch.search_text_value+"%' ");
            }

            /*
             * NORMAL SEARCH
             */

            else 
                query.append("SELECT * FROM gps WHERE adresse6 LIKE '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%' OR adressE1 LIKE  '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse2 LIKE '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse3 LIKE '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse4 LIKE '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%'  OR adresse5 LIKE '%"+Map.search_text_value+"%' ");

            //select * FROM "+articlesTable.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE addresse1 LIKE%"+Masp.search_text_value+"%\" OR addresse2 LIKE%"+Map.search_text_value+"% OR addresse1 LIKE%"+Map.search_text_value+"%\" OR addresse4 LIKE%"+Map.search_text_value+"%\" OR addresse5 LIKE%"+Map.search_text_value+"%\"

            cursor=this.database.rawQuery(query.toString(),null);

            System.out.println("cursor: "+query.toString());

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())

            {
                do

                {
                    Article a=new Article();

                    a.setEnseigne(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ENSEIGNE)));
                    a.setTel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.TEL)));
                    a.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.TYPE)));

                    a.setFax(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.FAX)));
                    a.setLatitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.LATITUDE)));
                    a.setLongitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.LONGITUDE)));
                    a.setNom(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.NOM)));

                    a.setAdresse1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE1)));
                    a.setAdresse2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE2)));
                    a.setAdresse3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE3)));
                    a.setAdresse4(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE4)));
                    a.setAdresse5(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE5)));
                    a.setAdresse6(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.ADRESSE6)));

                    a.setHoraires1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE1)));
                    a.setHoraires2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE2)));
                    a.setHoraires3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE3)));
                    a.setHoraires4(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE4)));
                    a.setHoraires5(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE5)));
                    a.setHoraires6(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE6)));
                    a.setHoraires7(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(articlesTable.HORAIRE7)));

                    items.add(a);

                }

                while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }


            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){

                cursor.close();

            }
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return items;
    }
    //--here
    public boolean addArticle(Article a){
        this.database.beginTransaction();

        try{


            ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ENSEIGNE, a.enseigne);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.TEL, a.tel);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.FAX, a.fax);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.TYPE, a.type);



            contentValues.put(articlesTable.LATITUDE, a.latitude);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.LONGITUDE, a.longitude);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE1, a.adresse1);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE2, a.adresse2);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE3, a.adresse3);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE4, a.adresse4);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE5, a.adresse5);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.ADRESSE6, a.adresse6);

            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE1, a.horaires1);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE2, a.horaires2);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE3, a.horaires3);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE4, a.horaires4);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE5, a.horaires5);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE6, a.horaires6);
            contentValues.put(articlesTable.HORAIRE7, a.horaires7);

            this.database.insert(articlesTable.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
            this.database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }finally{
            this.database.endTransaction();
        }
        return true;
    }


    public boolean deleteArticle(String id){
        try
        {
            String query="delete from " + articlesTable.TABLE_NAME+" where "+articlesTable.NOM+"='"+id+"'";
            this.database.execSQL(query);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**UPDATE: Table gps is missing only in android version 2.3 and below! i compile the source on device 4.1.2 and above and it work. My problem is on android 2.3 and below versions.**

Comment: the gps table is missing. How is anyone supposed to see how to fix that without seeing the actual database ?

Comment: i think you might be problem with copy database so please first check that...

Comment: are you sure your database copy completely under /data/data/ directory..??

Comment: I faced this problem many times(once in interview). Sometimes onCreate() method does not called so table will not be created. Uninstall app and reinstall..and keep trying same.

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

```
no such table: gps: , while compiling: select * FROM gps WHERE type="Agence".
```

Be sure you have it and built before.

In `OpenHelper` class you have method `onCreate` where actually you generate your table.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE gps .......
    }
```

From your code we don't see how did you build it.

BTW, its not a big problem to create table if you haven't, no worries, but by this way you can prevent above mentioned errors.

Comment: yes i have it and on android 4.1.2 it loads well, the problem is on <=2.3 version

Comment: :"From your code we don't see how did you build it." The database is a .sql file saved in assets folder

Comment: @Nikita well, its not good, compile only on lowest version. You have min version property for that.

Comment: sure, if you compiled apk on 4.1.2, set min version 4.x to prevent to 2.3 to install this apk. Or do vice versa, compile on 2.3 and set min version 2.3.

Comment: yes but in my application minimum version is 2.1 and maximum latest version on the market

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion? Have you suppress warnings somewhere? because if you change minVersion you should get warning that api changed from 2.3 to 4.x

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />